# Rename Collection on Mac OS

Tags: collections

Maybe there's a problem with my set-up, but I can't find a way to rename collections. Left-clicking and double left-clicking just brings up the outliner context menu. Could it be a Mac OS specific problem? I'm using an Apple "Magic Mouse" and the emulate three-button set-up makes no difference.

Edit: To answer my own question, I find I'd inadvertently altered the outliner keymap in Preferences. What an idiot. Oddly, dbl-left clicking still doesn't work, but right-clicking now does. this will also turn out to be my own fault, but at least I can rename my collections.

Comment: Have you tried also with F2?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Mugnozzo. Situation resolved (see edit). My limited keyboard currently uses the F2 key for screen brightness.